# How to make a horizontal recyclerview appear bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I wanna to build the layout like the diagram below. When I click the button a horizontal `recyclerView` slide up and appear at the bottom of the screen under the `LinearLayout` which contain the button.

[image]

I looking to use bottom sheet.When the bottom sheet with `recyclerView` appear,but it cover the whole `LinearLayout` which contain the `button`.Here is my layout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
     android:paddingTop="5dp">       

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text:"Button"/>     

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
   app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So my question is,how can I make the horizontal `recyclerView` slide up and appear from the bottom of the screen? Am I going the right direction? Or have a better approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use bottomsheet and add recycle view inside bottom sheet.

Comment: try to follow steps for this from my answer, I tested it.

Comment: put your recyclerview in to BottomSheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in simple steps:

First keep your linear Layout orientation vertical by adding this.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

And then add recycler view below button inside linearLayout.Whenever you have to hide recyclerview keep the visibility of recyclerview as "gone" and to show keep visibility as "visible" like this.

Initially keep your recycler hidden in xml and by adding this line in xml

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Thrn whenver button is clciked make your recycler appear in java like this

```
yourRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Finally your xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="button"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        />
```

Comment: I tried this,it produce this error `The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout` so the recyclerview cant be inside the linear layout?

Comment: sorry my bad..I forgot to add   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" which is very important..now check the also..Also I removed  app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" which might have caused you that error

Answer (score 1):

try below steps,

First, define XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <RecycleView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

    </RecycleView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second, initially set `RecycleView` visibility `gone`.

Third, on click of `Button` set `RecycleView` visibility `visible` in run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library.

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

In XML Put RecyclerView in its layout

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```